# Sort list of ranges in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

```
rangeList = [range(15, 20), range(7, 10), range(11, 14)]
```

How do I sort the `rangeList`, so that the resulting list look like below, Sorting based on the start value of the range ?

```
sortedRangeList = [range(7, 10), range(11, 14), range(15, 20)]
```

Answer (score 7):

You could [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) based on the [`start`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) attribute of each `range`:

```
sorted(rangeList, key=lambda r: r.start)
# [range(7, 10), range(11, 14), range(15, 20)]
```

---

By applying the above transformation function in the `key` parameter, essentially `sorted` will be ordering the list based on the following result:

```
[r.start for r in rangeList]
# [15, 7, 11]
```

Comment: One possible variation will be to use: `result = sorted(rangeList, key=attrgetter('start'))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save memory usage and perform an "In Place" sorting:

```
rangeList.sort(key=lambda rng: rng[0])
print(rangeList)
```

Output:

> [range(7, 10), range(11, 14), range(15, 20)]

Otherwise, if you do not care about memory optimization, you can just use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html):

```
sorted_ranges = sorted(rangeList, key=lambda rng: rng[0])
```